# iptables fowarding rules

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have an iptables rule in the FORWARD section that looks like this:

```
17       0     0 CONFIRMED  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.30.240       tcp spt:587 dpt:587 ctorigdst 24.103.190.234
```

What command would I need to run to create that rule?

Answer (score 0):

Executing `iptables-save` will dump your current `iptables` ruleset to `stdout`, in turn showing you the commands used to create your firewall ruleset, minus the `iptables` command